# Yii CGridView search with "&" contains attributes

Tags: php, yii, filter, cgridview, ampersand

I am using Yii 1.1.15 framework.

I can't search & as a symbol in a attribute (ex. brand_name) in the query string. If I enter & symbol the URL looks like this:

```
localhost/doctors/brand/?brand[brand_name]=&&brand[brand_status]=
```

Here the case is `brand[brand_name]=&`. It does not consider the `&` and is taken as the next parameter termination, if i just encode that character, it becomes: `%26` so the url becomes `localhost/doctors/brand/?brand[brand_name]=%26&brand[brand_status]=` and it gives the correct result.

But how to encode the yii CGridView filter text data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Grammar and formattation

Answer (score 0):

`CGridView` uses GET as the default ajax type and `&` is the delimiter for http request's GET parameters, so you can't use this character as part of your search string. I think the solution is using POST instead of GET for ajax requests. For changing CGridView ajax parameter from GET to POST, add `'ajaxType' => "POST"` to your cgridview options:

```
 <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
      'id'=>'...',
      'ajaxType' => "POST",
      'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
      'filter'=>$model,
      'columns'=>array(
         ...
       ),
 )); ?>
```

Comment: I tryed but it's not working, i am used also 'enableHistory'=>true, can you give a expample.

Comment: Are you sure?! I tested it in my CGridView and it worked fine. I entered `&` as a search filter and the grid send it to action without any problem!